# While working with selenium+java, the geolocation is not enabled in Chrome Headless mode, however it works perfectly in without headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I've this html that I got fromW3Schools

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I've selenium code like this without headless mode,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.html");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).getText());
    System.out.println("*******************************");
}
```

and output is :

```
'*******************************

Latitude: 13.009112499999999

Longitude: 77.7006038

'*******************************
```

but when I run with **headless** mode,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.html");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).getText());
    System.out.println("*******************************");
}
```

Output is :

```
'********************************

'*******************************
```

What am I missing?
I had to use headless only and I'm not able to enable the **geolocation** in chrome headless mode.